# Matlab subplots with fixed height and width

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure with 12 subplots, arranged in a 6 by 2 matrix. I want the figure to fit on a A4 paper such that I can include it in a corresponding LaTex document later on. In the end, it should look like the graphs in [Fiscal news and macroeconomic volatility, page 2593](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kZmB.jpg). My result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GADol.jpg) so far.

I have two problems though to get the same result:

1. The subplots should all have the same width and height.
2. The max and min of the y axis of the subplots should correspond to the y values of the graph, i.e. if the graph is only in the negative space, then the maximum value of the y axis should be around 0 as well.

My code (this is a simplified version) looks like this so far:

```
figure
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters');
set(gcf, 'PaperType', 'A4');
for s=1:12
    subplot(6,2,s)
    plot((1:30),M_.endo_names(s,:),'b','LineWidth',1);
    hold on;
    plot([0,30],[0,0],'k-','LineWidth',0.2);
    hold off;
    title(deblank(M_.endo_names(s,:)));
end
```

Although I have found threads that answer question 1, I was not able to apply their solutions to my problem. They proposed to use

```
subplot('Position',[left bottom width height])
```

which never looks like what I need.

I am happy to hear about your solutions! Thank you

Comment: How does `subplot` not give you equally sized axes?

Comment: As you can see in the picture of my results, they are all of the same height. However, I want the height to be larger, in particular I want to be able to define the height. As of now, one can hardly get an impression of the graph because the graphs are very little.

Comment: Not an answer but note that you could us e the pgfplot package from LaTex to include your plots directly, they would look nicer than an image.

Comment: @Justus oops, didn't see the link. What values are you using in your `Position` vector if you try to set the PV pair manually?

Answer (score 0):

`axis` handle should be helpful. Try this code:

```
figure
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters');
set(gcf, 'PaperType', 'A4');
for s=1:12
    subplot(6,2,s)
    plot((1:30),M_.endo_names(s,:),'b','LineWidth',1),axis([0 30 min(M_.endo_names(s,:)) max(M_.endo_names(s,:))]) 
    hold on;
    plot([0,30],[0,0],'k-','LineWidth',0.2);
    hold off;
    title(deblank(M_.endo_names(s,:)));
end
```

This will give you graphs with y-axes values ranging from the minimum value to the maximum value of the variables